# what can i do in compositing to get this looking more real like the original image

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes, lighting, photorealism

I'm trying to recreate this backrooms pool hallway scene.
[image]

This is my current render

[image]

Obviously, there are some differences like the chair in the back, the camera angle, or the tile size. However, I'm curious as to how I could make it look more like the original in terms of how much it looks like a real photo. I feel like it's some subtle difference. I can tell that mine looks faker than the original, but I can't figure out what needs to be changed or added

*I would link my blend file but I don't know how

Comment: Currently, all I have in the compositor is a very subtle fog glow glare node, and a lens distortion with jitter and a tiny bit of dispersion

Comment: This is primarily about the type of lighting, not about compositing.

Comment: You can play with the Compositor but in my opinion the first thing to do is to give Depth of Field to your camera

Comment: @quellenform Im using just a hdri of a sunny field solely because its slightly yellow

Comment: @moonboots Ill try that, im surprised with myself that i hadn't YET

Comment: Also in the Compositor add a bit of blur, too much sharpness makes the picture a bit unrealistic imho

Comment: Please share blend file with us (don't forget to pack the images), then we can take a closer look at lighting conditions: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The big difference here is the lack of blur in your image. You can add blur in the *Compositor*, but first select your camera and enable the *Depth of Field* option. You can choose the object (or empty) on which you'll focus (or choose a *Focus Distance* instead), and the important setting is the *F-Stop* value (decrease it a lot). There are also some settings in the *Render* panel.

[image]

Comment: Usually I love your answers and I could already learn a lot from you. But here I have to disagree with you: The blur in this example image comes from the fact that it is of poor quality and has been scaled up. Adding blur in this way is unlikely to achieve photorealism. And why should a photo have any depth of field at all at this distance from the object in bright sunlight? You would hardly shoot with an open aperture ...just my opinion.

Comment: Blur is the big difference I see between the 2 pictures, pictures that are too sharp can look really unrealistic (it's one of the flaws of heavily CGIed movies in my opinion, the image is too clean), as for the aperture I agree but you can still have a bit of DoF with powerful lights, and here it looks like the background is more blurry than the foreground. What is the difference you would point out here? Of course the water could be a bit better and the wall a bit dirtier but it won't make a bit difference imho.

Comment: The difference? It clearly needs a sun here in addition to the HDRI, in my opinion. Judging from the angle of incidence: late afternoon, warm light, slightly hazy air, clear sky. The difficulty is more in matching the sun position with the HDRI (but there are addons for that). Also, you would need to increase the reflectivity of the ceramic surface so that the stray light is enhanced a bit. And the joints of the tiles could be darker.

Comment: In addition, there is a slight shadow further back in the room, which probably comes from a glass surface outside the image. There are obviously still objects here that are between the scenery and the light source.

Comment: yes there are a lot of details that can be improved but DoF is the main cheat trick imho, but I'm lazy   ;)

Comment: However, the multitude of your wonderful answers does not exactly lead to the assumption that you are lazy ;-)

Comment: ah ah thank you, it takes work to be lazy

Answer (score 0):

Under the *[Color Management](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html)* settings, for the *Look* setting, I would try a higher contrast.  You could also try sharpening the render with a [filter node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/filter.html).

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9AT7H4GGrA) is a useful Blender Guru tutorial titled, "The Secret Ingredient to Photorealism."